# javascript- facebook uploading photo

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am working on a chrome extension project and i'm trying to upload photo to an facebook album but it always returns the following response no matter which image i try to upload.

```
 {
   "error": {
      "message": "This message contains content that has been blocked by our security systems.",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 368
   }
}
```

Here is my code:

```js
var canvas = document.createElement('CANVAS');
 var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
 var img = new Image;
 img.crossOrigin = 'Anonymous';
 img.onload = function(){
  canvas.height = img.height;
  canvas.width = img.width;
    ctx.drawImage(img,0,0);
    var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL( 'image/png');
   blob = dataURItoBlob(dataURL);
     goon(blob);
     canvas = null; 
 };
 img.src = "image url";

function dataURItoBlob(dataURI) {
var byteString = atob(dataURI.split(',')[1]);
var ab = new ArrayBuffer(byteString.length);
var ia = new Uint8Array(ab);
for (var i = 0; i < byteString.length; i++) {
    ia[i] = byteString.charCodeAt(i);
}
return new Blob([ab], { type: 'image/png' });
}
              
                                      
 function goon(kkv){
 var formdata= new FormData();

formdata.append("access_token", "Acces token");
formdata.append("message", "test message");
formdata.append("source", kkv);
formdata.append("privacy",  "{'value':'EVERYONE'}");
try {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'https://graph.facebook.com/me/photos',
        type: "POST",
        data: formdata,
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        cache: false,
        error: function (shr, status, data) {
            console.log("error " + data + " Status " + shr.status);
        },
        success: function (msg) {
            //successful
        }
    });
} catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
}
 }
```

I am using facebook graph api v2.3 to get access token( with extended permissions)

I have tried to use url parameter insted of source but it gave me the same response

```
formdata.append("url", 'image url');
```

Is there any way to do this without access token, i wanna use it just for my facebook account on my computer.If not, how can i get rid of this error ?

Answer (score 0):

No, you need an access token to post to facebook programatically. I am getting a similar error and my research seems to indicate it has to do with the frequency in which you post a url.  Especially, if you are using and app and the url's domain is outside of the app's domain.  Best answer is to either post less frequently or use Facebook's Ad API, but then you might run into costs.

Comment: Since you said it's about frequency, i have tried with a new facebook account on a different computer.I got same response.I don'T use an app, im trying the code on chrome's console.

Comment: Ok, well it might be an issue with you get command. The parameter for the pic url is 'picture'. You also need to use a token with the correct permissions set and use the feed edge to post. Can you reply with the HTTP POST command your code is sending through? Also, see the FB ref page for a list of params: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.3/post

Comment: I'm using exactly the same code on my first post.It is working for feed(picture parameter) but what i want is uploading a photo to an album not posting to wall.I am sure that i have correct permission(publish_actions)So i think this is the right ref page: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.3/photo